# gRPC testing stats are not collected

Tags: grpc, locust

I am following the [grpc example](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/grpc/locustfile.py) from the example and use the same `locustfile.py` and replace the stub and server with my own stub (class and calls) and server. I can verify that the **requests are sent successfully and the responses are correct**, however, locust fails to collect any stats. The output is like this for the entire run:

```
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails  |     Avg     Min     Max  Median  |   req/s failures/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregated                                                         0     0(0.00%)  |       0       0       0       0  |    0.00    0.00
```

What I am missing here? Any pointer or direction to debug is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replaced the stub and server with your own code, you're likely no longer firing the event for Locust with the request stats. In the example you linked, that's on [line 46](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/55525a50240704fcb48bc24fb8e7ba417995af09/examples/grpc/locustfile.py#L46).

```
events.request.fire(**request_meta)
```

It doesn't have to be there, but it has to be somewhere. When using custom clients like the gRPC client, you need to tell Locust what happens. That's done with [request events](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?#locust.event.Events.request). Without those, Locust has no idea what the code you're running is doing.