# Locust while running as library with grpc client not outputting stats

Tags: python, grpc, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

We are trying to add a locust grpc client and got the code from examples directory [here](https://github.com/locustio/locust/tree/master/examples/grpc).

Our use case is such that locust will used as a library and not through UI.

The issues we are seeing stats outputted either in csv file or the code. I only difference between what we code we see in locust doc [here](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html#example-writing-a-grpc-user-client) and our code is service is started independently.

The issue is reproduced in this GitHub repo : https://github.com/saurabhsharma721/grpc_locust_stats_repro_prj

This issue is only observed in library mode. If we run it through ui the stats produced are correct. Please help.

Comment: I see we have similar question but want to check where to place request events inside the test. A code snippet will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229131/grpc-testing-stats-are-not-collected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but have you tried adding this?

```
# start a greenlet that save current stats to history
gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)
```

(from the documentation https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html)

Comment: did that but did not help

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you verify that the requests are actually being made when running as a library? (add a print statement to the task or something). Other than that, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: The tasks are running as logs get printied with response. Trying to dig why ui is different that not non ui

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using following question with following code :

Added two static methods to be called on init and tear down

```
 @staticmethod
    def on_init(environment, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        print("Perform global setup to create a global state in LocustRunner")

 @staticmethod
    def on_quit(environment, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        print('Perform global teardown to clear the global state in LocustRunner')
```

Then added this code in driver

```
events.init.add_listener(LocustRunner.on_init)
env = Environment(user_classes=[TestClass], events=events)
# Using local runner in start
runner = env.create_local_runner()
# init event
env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner)
Driver code 
# quit event
env.events.quitting.fire(environment=env, reverse=True)
```

There is already a stack-overflow answer for this but unable to search for that currently